# Why do my native libraries crash .NET Core with an "illegal isntruction" error?

Tags: .net-core, centos

So I just got done porting a console app (which uses Intel MKL) to Mono, but it's 100% slower than native. So now I am trying to use .NET Core. However, the same native libraries (like libmkl_rt.so) that were working with Mono now crash .net core with a non-descriptive "illegal instruction". That's it, nothing else, program exits, no line number or info.

The app works under Windows.

What I tried

- set MKL_VERBOSE=1 (no change)
- publish the app as self contained (no change)
- mess a bit with DLLImport parameters (in fact I tried to change library name to a non-existent name to verify at least it's being found, and in this case in fact I get a stack trace... so the libmkl_rt.so IS being found, but it throws a problem internally).

Trying different things I was also able to get "stack overflow" instead of "illegal instruction" though I am not sure how. Again no stack trace.
I have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set. The native library was working with mono (same OS image).

Any way to output some debug info would be appreciated.

Comment: Now it gives Segmentation fault instead. I don't think I changed anything

Comment: Same story on Ubuntu server